# Checking entries in EditText object inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have list box that consist EditBox in each row of listbox.  On button Save I have to check is all EditText object filled with data.

This is how is constructed adapter for ListView:

```
public class LvAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;

    public LvAdapter(Context c){
         mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         context = c;
    }       

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return list.size();
        return cGlobal.listOfWork.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        convertView=null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();


        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_produced_quantities_rows, null); // this is your cell

        holder.orderID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pqOrderID);
        holder.orderID.setTag(position);
        holder.orderID.setText(cGlobal.listOfWork.get(position).get("OrderID"));

        holder.productCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pqProductCode);
        holder.productCode.setTag(position);
        holder.productCode.setText(cGlobal.listOfWork.get(position).get("ProductCode"));


        holder.productionID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pqProductionID);
        holder.productionID.setTag(position);
        holder.productionID.setText(cGlobal.listOfWork.get(position).get("ProductionID"));

        holder.operationID = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pqOperationID);
        holder.operationID.setTag(position);
        holder.operationID.setText(cGlobal.listOfWork.get(position).get("OperationID"));

        holder.quantity = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
        holder.quantity.setTag(position);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.quantity.setFocusable(true);

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final int tag_position=(Integer) holder.quantity.getTag();
        holder.quantity.setId(tag_position);


        if (upisano.get(holder.productionID.getText().toString()) != null)
        {
            holder.quantity.setText(upisano.get(holder.productionID.getText().toString()));
        }


         holder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                       int count) {                          

                     }                   


               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                       int after) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {                      

               }

           });  

         btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText tvEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);

                if (tvEdit.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    return convertView;
    }       

}

public class ViewHolder {
    EditText quantity;
    TextView orderID;
    TextView productCode;
    TextView productionID;  
    TextView operationID;
}
```

Application crashes on line:

```
if (tvEdit.getText().toString().isEmpty())
```

Error type:

> java.lang.NullPointerExpection

What's wrong?

Comment: Where you initialize btnSave?

Comment: You say there must be a value in every EditText in every Line. However lines that are currently not visible won't be checked even if your code happened to be correct. I would have a list of Strings in my Adapter in which I mirror my EditText values. And on save I would check the list, not the EditTexts that are currently loaded in the list

Comment: I believe your (R.id.txtQuantity) EditText doen't belog to listView Row. If it is then you define it in this way..
 EditText tvEdit = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);

Comment: It belongs, I've checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken one boolean ArrayList in adapter :

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> quantityCheckList;
```

Initialize with as no of item of list in adapter constructor :

```
quantityCheckList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
for(int i=0;i<cGlobal.listOfWork.size();i++){
     quantityCheckList.add(false);
}
```

Change appropriate item boolean state when EditText value changed :

```
holder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
     }
     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
     }
     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.toString().trim().length()>0){
           quantityCheckList.add(position,true);
        }else{
           quantityCheckList.add(position,false);
        }
     }
});
```

Define one custom method in adapter to check for any empty EditText :

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
   boolean isAnyEmpty=true;
   for (int i=0;i<quantityCheckList.size();i++){
        if(!quantityCheckList.get(i)){
           isAnyEmpty=false;
           break;
        }
   }
   return isAnyEmpty;
}
```

Now implement btnSave click listener in activity and check empty value using adapter isEmpty() :

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if (adapter.isEmpty())
      {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else
      {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Button is initialized inside onCreate(). Your solution breaks on if statement.

Comment: @Josef,then why you implement click listener in adapter instead of activity.

Comment: Because this is the only whay that I know how to aceess to getView :(

Comment: @Josef,what is your actual requirement like when btnSave click Check list all EditText value is it ?

Comment: When user press btnSave app should check all EditText boxes if there are values. If not it should inform user that he forget to enter values in some of EditText boxes.

Comment: @Josef,Okay just wait for some try i edited my ans which achieved your requirement.

Comment: Your previous solution was also correct before you made changes. Thanks @Haresh Chhelana!!

Comment: @Josef,No brother which is i thought that btnSave in ListView but as now given solution is properly implemented as per your requirement.

Comment: hi, i have used such like function as you wrote: 
public void isEmpty(){
   boolean isAnyEmpty=true;
   for (int i=0;i<quantityCheckList.size();i++){
        if(!quantityCheckList.get(i)){
           isAnyEmpty=false;
           break;
        }
   }
}
but i need to add animation and setError on EditText for the particular EditText for the user assistance , please help me how may I do this

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
   EditText tvEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
```

to

```
   EditText tvEdit = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);
```

and make sure you've `EditText` with id **txtQuantity** in your layout `activity_produced_quantities_rows`

### OR try this way

```
  if (holder.quantity.toString().isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **holder.quantity** in your anonymous inner class (OnClickListener) because holder is a final variable. If I'm correct the anonymous inner class takes that final variable in its constructor under the hood and the variable becomes an instance variable of that object.

So it would go like this:

```
if (holder.quantity.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else ...
```